# Parsing Java source code using Python to identify SQL statements and fetch tables used in the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I need to create a parser using Python to parse Java files and get tables and columns used by code. The code uses all possible syntax (select, update, insert, delete) to connect to tables. Few examples are :-

```
private static String query1 = "select t1.col1 as COLUMN1, t1.col2 as COLUMN2 from table1 t1 where t1.col3 is not NULL";
public String query="Select col1 From table1 Where col2='" + value + "'";
String query="UPDATE table2 SET col1='"+val1+"' WHERE col2 = '"+val2+"' AND col3 = '"+val3+"' AND (col4 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2='"+val+"'))";
String query="DELETE table3 WHERE col4 = '"+val4+"' AND col5 = '"+val5+"' AND (col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table2 WHERE col5='"+someVal+"'))";
String query = "select count(*) AS COUNT1 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (select DISTINCT t1.col1, t1.col2 from table1 t1 WHERE t1.col3=? or t1.col4=? or t1.col5=? "
            + "UNION select DISTINCT t2.col1,t2.col2 from table2 t2 WHERE t2.col3=? or t2.col4=? or "
            + "t2.col5=?)) ";
```

I took a look in ANTLR3 grammer, but it is too complicated to understand and also could not find a link to understand the usage.
I am new to Python and need help to achieve this functionality.

Comment: When you say you "need help", it might be useful to show what you've tried from a code perspective. Otherwise, looks like you're asking for someone to do it all for you

Comment: I started by looking into ANTLR3 as whenever I googled for "Java Parser Python", it came up. I have started Python 2 days back (previously worked on Java), so I am taking baby steps. Need pointers to make a correct start and do it myself.

Comment: Brute force regex? `(FROM|UPDATE|DELETE) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: As far as I know, ANTLR is for Java to parse (or generate) other languages, not from Python. I think you're looking for something like https://github.com/musiKk/plyj

Comment: If you are not comfortable with complex grammars, you aren't going to succeed.  First you need a grammar for Java so you can pick out potential SQL strings;  you probably need data flow analysis to veriy that such strings are actually *used* as SQL and don't just happen to contain text that looks like.  Then you'll need to assemble string fragments to build whole SQL commands.  Once you're there, now you need a full SQL parser to inspect the strings.  Java and SQL are not simple langauges.  Don't expect this to be a simple task.

Comment: If you don't care if your answer is right, you can write bad perl scripts to heuristically pick up literal strings and tear them apart.  You have to really not care if the answer is right to go down this path.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried Brute Force Regex, works well for queries on single line, but if query spans multiple lines (frequent scenario in the code) then its problematic.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the statements you need to process are fairly consistent with the ones you display in your question then I would say your problem is not Java parsing but SQL parsing. You could do the Java parsing in a fairly rough-and-ready way with the following sort of script which turns Java lines into Python strings, and which also shows how to initial parsing with the [sqlparse](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/) library.

```
import re
import sqlparse

sql_lines = []
one_sql_line = ''
with open('nayan.txt') as nayan:
    for line in nayan:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith(';'):
            one_sql_line += line[:-1]
            one_sql_line = one_sql_line[1+one_sql_line.find('='):]
            one_sql_line = re.subn(r'"\s*\+\s*(?P<var>[a-z0-9_]+)\s*\+\s*"', 'JAVA_\g<var>', one_sql_line, re.I)[0]
            one_sql_line = re.subn(r'"\s*\+\s*"', '', one_sql_line)[0]
            one_sql_line = one_sql_line.replace('"+', 'JAVA_').replace('+"', '')
            sql_lines.append(one_sql_line.strip())
            one_sql_line =''
        else:
            one_sql_line += line

for sql_line in sql_lines:
    print (sql_line)
    stmt = sqlparse.parse(sql_line)
    print (stmt)
```

This yields the following result.

```
"select t1.col1 as COLUMN1, t1.col2 as COLUMN2 from table1 t1 where t1.col3 is not NULL"
(<Statement '"selec...' at 0x23AA65D2660>,)
"Select col1 From table1 Where col2='JAVA_value'"
(<Statement '"Selec...' at 0x23AA65D2750>,)
"UPDATE table2 SET col1='JAVA_val1' WHERE col2 = 'JAVA_val2' AND col3 = 'JAVA_val3+'"' AND (col4 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2='JAVA_val'))"
(<Statement '"UPDAT...' at 0x23AA65D2840>,)
"DELETE table3 WHERE col4 = 'JAVA_val4' AND col5 = 'JAVA_val5' AND (col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table2 WHERE col5='JAVA_someVal'))"
(<Statement '"DELET...' at 0x23AA65D29A8>,)
"select count(*) AS COUNT1 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (select DISTINCT t1.col1, t1.col2 from table1 t1 WHERE t1.col3=? or t1.col4=? or t1.col5=? UNION select DISTINCT t2.col1,t2.col2 from table2 t2 WHERE t2.col3=? or t2.col4=? or t2.col5=?)) "
(<Statement '"selec...' at 0x23AA65D2A98>,)
```

If I take a simpler SQL statement I can show how it's possible to parse it for its elements.

```
>>> import sqlparse
>>> a_query = 'SELECT * FROM planets WHERE planets > 0'
>>> parsed = sqlparse.parse(a_query)[0]
>>> parsed.tokens
[<DML 'SELECT' at 0x29496B5B468>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x29496B5B408>, <Wildcard '*' at 0x29496B5B4C8>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x29496B5B528>, <Keyword 'FROM' at 0x29496B5B588>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x29496B5B5E8>, <Identifier 'planets' at 0x29496B42ED0>, <Whitespace ' ' at 0x29496B5B6A8>, <Where 'WHERE ...' at 0x29496B42E58>]
>>> for token in parsed.tokens:
...     token.ttype, token.value
...     
(Token.Keyword.DML, 'SELECT')
(Token.Text.Whitespace, ' ')
(Token.Wildcard, '*')
(Token.Text.Whitespace, ' ')
(Token.Keyword, 'FROM')
(Token.Text.Whitespace, ' ')
(None, 'planets')
(Token.Text.Whitespace, ' ')
(None, 'WHERE planets > 0')
```

**Caution**: Just be aware that I have almost no experience of using this library.